# Applying homography to a set of points and displaying the points on the warped image

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, homography

I have a homography matrix that I use to get a bird's eye view of my original image using imwarp.

How can I display a set of points that I transfer using the same homography on the warped image correctly?

```
close all

img = imread('test2.jpg');

pts_img = [[1612.6 2509.3]; [4002.5 2393]; [3557.3 1040.9]; [1684.1 1050.7]]';
pts_world = 100*[[0 0]; [10 0]; [10 8]; [0 8]]';

tform = fitgeotrans(pts_img', pts_world','projective');

warped_img = imwarp(img, tform);

pts_img_h = [pts_img; ones(1,size(pts_img,2))]; % convert to homogeneous coordinates 

H = tform.T';  % homography matrix

% transform pts_img using the homography matrix
pts_t_h = H*pts_img_h;
% converting to image coordinates
pts_t = pts_t_h(1:end-1,:) ./ repmat(pts_t_h(end,:), size(pts_t_h,1)-1, 1);

figure(1)
imshow(warped_img);
figure(2)
warped_img_marked = insertMarker(warped_img, pts_t', 'o', 'size', 10);
imshow(warped_img_marked);

figure(3)
imshow(img);
figure(4)
img_marked = insertMarker(img, pts_img', 'o', 'size', 10);
imshow(img_marked);
```

Is there a way of displaying the transformed points on the warped image?[image: original image]
[image: warped image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can try using [insertMarker](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertmarker.html). It's hard answering your question, because it's not executable. `pts_w` is missing, `e2h` and `h2e` are also missing...

Comment: Using `hold on` and `plot`

Comment: @Rotem Thank you very much for responding. I have edited the post to make it executable. insertMarker doesn't seem to work as the (0,0) world coordinate in the warped image is not located at (0,0) in the warped image coordinate. Is there a way of matching the warped image coordinate with my world coordinates? Thanks again for the help

Comment: @AnderBiguri, unfortunately, simply plotting over the image doesn't work as the coordinates do not match.

Comment: If you have the image coordinates, then they should. Likely you are just mistaking the fact that image axis start on top left, as opposed to bottom left for the plot.